# how to change web services reference,when deployment

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I am a Mono Android developer.

when I complete my App and deployment to production server ,I need to change web services to another IIS server,different with test one.

I try following code:

```
wfqry = new AndroidApp.WFQuery.WFQuery();

wfqry.Url = "http://192.123.123.1/APPS/WebServices/WFQ.asmx"

wfqry.Discover();
```

but get error message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The url 'http://xxxxxx/APP/WebServices/WFQ.asmx' does not point to a valid discovery document
  at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Discover (string) <IL 0x00038, 0x001ec>

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Discover (string) <IL 0x00033, 0x000a3>

  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Discover () <IL 0x00024, 0x0016f>

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Discover () <IL 0x00032, 0x00083>

  at test5.Activity1.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x0005d] in d:\TempData2\TestPrij\test5\test5\Activity1.cs:35

  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.4-series/c6e52015/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1490

  at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.a16901a2-0117-4e00-8013-5fc10b948c06 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
```

what wrong is it?

or

please tell me how to easy change web service reference whitout delete and reAdd web reference

thank you very much!